# can i avoid zoo category to split my list?

Tags: joomla, categories, zoo

is there a way not to split items in Zoo Category to multiple webpages, but to display them in a full list ?

http://www.luislabatonandpartners.com/en/selected-projects

Thanks

Comment: Guess it's a **Joomla** question. Please redirect it to http://joomla.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Edit the Zoo Category, in the right hand open de Configuration tab, uncheck "items per page" and set to 999.